# Nested IF conditions with multiple logic operators (AND, OR)

Tags: php, if-statement, optimization, logical-operators

This is my first question on stackoverflow and hopefully somebody, beside me, needs this type of code.

The code I've written is working fine, but I would like to know how it can be improved or if there is a better way to achieve the same result.

```
// Do NOT include files for '404' and pages 'abc' or 'def' with slug '123'
if (  $pageName !== '404'  ) 
{ 

    if (( $pageName == 'abc' ) && ( $pageSlug == '123' ) 
             OR ( $pageName == 'def' ) && ( $pageSlug == '123' )) {

        return NULL;

    }

    else {

        // include file
        require_once ( '/file.php' );

        // Do NOT include for page 'def'
        if ( $pageName !== 'def' ) {

            // include file
            require_once ( file_2.php' );

        }

    }

};
```

Comment: Since the code works, it does not belong here. You should post at code review.

Comment: You could make this minor simplification: `if (( $pageName == 'abc' || $pageName == 'def') && $pageSlug == '123' )`. As you appear to know, `&&` takes precedence over `||`, so you override that by using parentheses.

Comment: Thanks for the simplification. The code is more readeble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being that you're in a function already you could cut down on some of your nesting with an immediate return on a 404. In addition the else is not necessary due to the 'return NULL' and I think breaking up your if-or into 2 ifs makes it more readable:

```
function your_func_name($pageName, $pageSlug) {
   if ( $pageName == '404' ) {
       return;
   }

   if ( $pageName == 'abc' && $pageSlug == '123' ) {
      return NULL;
   }

   if ( $pageName == 'def' && $pageSlug == '123' ) {
      return NULL;
   }

   // include file
   require_once ( '/file.php' );

   // Do NOT include for page 'def'
   if ( $pageName !== 'def' ) {
      // include file
      require_once ( 'file_2.php' );
   }
}
```